# Integral involving nested Log

Tags: definite-integrals

I've been trying to solve this integral for a few days.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(t+n\right)\ln\left(\frac{t+n}{t}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(t+n\right)\ln\left(\frac{t+n}{t}\right)\right)-1\right)dt$$

For $n\gt0$.

I'm able to solve most of the integral until I got stuck trying to solve

$$\int\log\left(\log\left(\frac{t+n}{t}\right)\right)dt$$

Edit:
We first see that with a substitution we take $n$ out of the problem. Thus the integral we want to solve has a value of $0.38033\dots$  @Yuriy S has helped find an alternate form for integral.  I want to contribute another alternate form that can be derived from Yuriy's form.
$$I_1=-\frac{1}{4}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{e^s-1}{2e^s}+\ln\left(e^s-1\right)-\ln\left(s\right)\right)\frac{e^s}{\left(e^s-1\right)^2}ds$$

Another Update:
I discovered that

$$\begin{align}
I_1+\frac14&=-\int_x^\infty\frac{1}{t(e^t-1)}dt-\left(-\frac1x-\frac{\ln{x}}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!(n-1)}x^{n-1}\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Ei}(-xn)-\left(-\frac1x-\frac{\ln{x}}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!(n-1)}x^{n-1}\right)
\end{align}$$ for $0\lt x\lt 2\pi$.  Here the non-integral part on the rhs is the series expansion of the integral part at $x=0$.

Comment: Numerically, the value of the integral seems to be about $0.38033n$.

Comment: I believe the value to be $\frac12\left(\ln 2\pi-\gamma\right)-\frac14$

Answer (score 4):

Simplify first by substitution:

$$t=nu$$

$$I(n)=n\int_0^{\infty}\left((u+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)-\ln\left((u+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)\right)-1\right)du$$

So we need to find the following constant:

$$I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\left((u+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)-\ln\left((u+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)\right)-1\right)du$$

Frankly, this looks bad, I doubt there's an exact solution. The numerical value, as stated by  MathIsFun7225 is about $0.3803301$.

Using some substitutions, we can transform the integral to:

$$I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{s}{e^s-1}+\ln(e^s-1)-\ln s-1\right)\frac{e^s ds}{(e^s-1)^2}$$

The function:

$$f(s)=s+(e^s-1)\left(\ln(e^s-1)-\ln s-1\right)$$

Has a nice Taylor expansion around zero:

> $$f(s)= \frac{s^3}{8}+\frac{s^4}{16}+\frac{11s^5}{576}+\frac{5s^6}{1152}+\frac{41s^7}{51840}+\frac{5s^8}{41472}+\dots \tag{1}$$
>
> $$I_1= \int_0^{\infty}f(s)\frac{e^s ds}{(e^s-1)^3} \tag{2}$$

Consider:

> $$J_k=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{s^k e^s ds}{(e^s-1)^3}$$

In the answer(s) to this question: [An integral for the difference of zeta functions $\zeta (s-1)-\zeta(s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330977/269624) it is shown that:

> $$J_k=\frac{k!}{2} (\zeta(k-1)-\zeta(k)) \tag{3}$$

---

Finally, summing a few first terms of the series (1), we obtain a number close to numerical value of the integral.

For example three first terms give us the value $0.3079 \ldots$.

The first six terms give $0.3668 \dots$.

> However, since the Taylor series (1) has a finite radius of convergence, the series obtained for the integral is asymptotic in nature and most likely diverges. But as usual with asymptotic series, finitely many terms should give a good approximation for the integral.

The series terms all have the same sign up to $s^{20}$, then we encounter the first sign change. Summing all the terms for $k=3, \dots, 20$, we obtain:

$$I_1 \approx 0.3803246 \dots$$

Which is a good approximation. I'm not sure what number of terms will give the best agreement with the exact value.

---

**Update:**

Using @automaticallyGenerated's answer, I have checked the asymptotic series numerically, and here's the result for different number of terms (starting with $k=3$:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 15 & 0.380130074058105238689754781268 \\
 16 & 0.380223929458113985169381973291 \\
 17 & 0.380272711854003260001162359969 \\
 18 & 0.380298890136158789781977313273 \\
 19 & 0.380315792727508660246473419445 \\
 20 & 0.380324694728276221658188520931 \\
 21 & 0.380323061796211720843375783973 \\
 22 & 0.380322359261040332671841945024 \\
 23 & 0.380338844375899979977446596772 \\
 24 & 0.380347115006252429034820349587 \\
 25 & 0.380297504104854694212803005034 \\
 26 & 0.380272706474517002755450053827 \\
 27 & 0.380464567324088204449788570410 \\
 28 & 0.380560498418357337146304250784 \\
 29 & 0.379700469605659832230621914362 \\
 30 & 0.379270457893190348577342716132 \\
 31 & 0.383724367550841791140185335387 \\
 32 & 0.385951317329242809053234753014 \\
 33 & 0.359568287367679813690910184314 \\
 34 & 0.346376786006546776686420830652 \\
 35 & 0.523655288520764751498176067439 \\
 36 & 0.612294499198448476853004251809 \\
 37 & -0.72901761727886247456922591902 \\
 38 & -1.39967353904013645644838768421 \\
 39 & 9.9527821590780141647092153950 \\
 40 & 15.6290094947770368344784462912 \\
 41 & -91.221244446733759055679027656 \\
 42 & -144.646369270054172239030454206 \\
 43 & 967.80090283422936072262158677 \\
 44 & 1524.02452894976299543567171838 \\
 45 & -11226.0112127462193171191333164 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Clearly, the series doesn't converge and the best approximation is achieved around $k_m=20$.

Comment: Why don't you use $$f(x)=\frac{s}{e^s-1}+\ln(e^s-1)-\ln s-1$$ and $$J_k = \int_0^\infty \frac{s^k e^s ds}{(e^s-1)^2} = k! \cdot \zeta(k)$$? It seems like it would be easier to approximate that way.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated, I get rid of the logarithm that way, after series expansion. But your way is good as well

Comment: I believe we have $\frac{s}{e^s-1}+\ln(e^s-1)-\ln(s)-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(2n+1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!(2n)}s^{2n}}$ for $|s|\lt 2\pi$

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated, regarding your answer, the obvious problem is that the series for $f(s)$, either mine or yours has a finite radius of convergence, which means that termwise integration can only give us an asymptotic series. Good for approximation, but diverges

Comment: Right, do you know of any techniques to analytically continue the domain of the series?

Comment: @tyobrien, we will need to expand around a different point then, I guess. Otherwise, just use the exact expression for $f(s)$ we already have (valid for any $s>0$), any analytic continuation should agree with it anyway.

Comment: @YuriyS Just graphing the first couple of terms, I think your Taylor series for $f(s)$ converges to $f(s)$.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated, it does, but only in some interval, I highly doubt it has infinite radius of convergence

Answer (score 2):

We can actually find a term by term expansion of the $f(s)=s+(e^s-1)\left(\ln(e^s-1)-\ln s-1\right)$ used in YuriyS's answer. If we rearrange $f(s)$, we get $$f(x) = (x+1-e^x) + (e^x-1)(\ln(e^x-1)-\ln(x))$$

If we look at $x+1-e^x$, this has a known Taylor series (which converges for all real) of $$-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

We also know that $$e^x-1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ which again converges for all real.

$\ln(e^x-1)-\ln(x)$ is a bit more tricky. If we differentiate it, we get $$\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} = 1+\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}$$ Here we can use the fact that $\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!} x^n$ where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers. If we divide by $x$ and add $1-\frac{1}{x}$, we get $$1+\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{B_n}{n!} x^{n-1}$$ Integrating, we then have that $$\ln(e^x-1)-\ln(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n! \cdot n}x^n$$

We now have that $$f(x) = -\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \cdot \left(\frac{x}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n! \cdot n}x^n\right) = -\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}  + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{B_m}{m! \cdot m}x^m$$

$$f(x) = -\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} +  \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{2(n-1)!}  + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \cdot \sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\frac{B_m}{(n-m)!m! \cdot m}x^n$$

Finally, we get the closed form for $a_n$ in $f(x) = \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n x^n$ as $$a_n = \frac{n-2}{2(n!)}+\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\frac{B_m}{(n-m)!m! \cdot m} = \sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\left(\frac{B_m}{(n-m)!m! \cdot m}+\frac{1}{2(n!)}\right)$$

Using the same $I_1 = \int_0^\infty f(s) \frac{e^s ds}{(e^s-1)^3}$ as YuriyS, we now want to find $$I_1 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n \frac{n!}{2} (\zeta(n-1)-\zeta(n)) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(a_{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!}{2}-a_{n}\frac{n!}{2}\right)\zeta(n)$$ I am not exactly sure what to do from here, but at least it is in the form of an infinite series instead of an integral.

Edit: As YuriyS mentioned in the comments, $a_n n!$ can be stated neatly as $b_n=\frac{n-2}{2}+\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\frac{B_m \binom{n}{m}}{m}$. This means that $$I_1 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2} (\zeta(n-1)-\zeta(n)) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{b_{n+1}}{2}-\frac{b_n}{2}\right)\zeta(n)$$

Edit 2: Unfortunately, these series will diverge, as mentioned in the comments, making it impossible for use in calculating $I_1$.

Comment: You can rewrite $a_n n!$ more neatly using $\binom{n}{m}$

Comment: The final series doesn't converge. See my edit. It's still an asymptotic series. Sometimes even when the series inside the integral converges, the termwise integration still leads to divergent series

Comment: Though in this case, why are you so sure that $\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!} x^n$ converges for all real $x$? Numerical experiments suggest otherwise, as for large $x$ the terms start to grow in absolute value